# closing specific files using command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

Quick question,

Let's say I have an image (named image.png) open on windows, is it possible to close ONLY THAT image using command prompt?

If so, how do I do it?

Thanks in an advance.

Comment: How did you open said file.

Comment: C:\> start image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq image.png*"
```

works fine for me (using IrfanView). Windowtitle is `image.png - IrvanView`. The wildcard `*` takes care of the string after the file name. Some other programs might have other title formats (like `image.png` only (above works too) or `Program name - image.png` (above doesn't work - wildcard can only handle "end of string", not "start of string"), then it must be changed to `taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq Programmname - image.png"` (or whatever your actual program's title is)

Comment: Feels like I'm on the right track, but not quite yet :D 
My image runs on window called _Photos - image.png_. In cmd  I used command: `taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq Photos - image.png*"` however cmd outputs: _INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria._

Comment: Hm. `Photos` seems to work differently. Try `tasklist /v` - it doesn't have the image name in the title. (or more specific: `tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq Microsoft.Photos.exe"`

Comment: Yes, this works: `taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq Microsoft.Photos.exe"` but it closes all open images, is it possible to specify exactly which one to close?

Comment: I'm afraid no. Those Systemapps don't work like "normal" programs. It doesn't tell the command processor which image is open (check with `tasklist /v`), so `cmd` has nothing to distinguish. Also, `Photos` doesn`t open different processes for several images, so there is just that one process (Btw: @Mark's solution has the same problem). Maybe PowerShell has more insight (don't know enough about PS to tell). I'll keep this answer because it might help others (who use another image viewer)

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic process where 'commandline LIKE "%image.png%"' call terminate
```

Note because this command line also has image.png in it wmic be terminated. Note quoting of < and >.

```
wmic process where 'commandline LIKE "%image.png%" and caption ^<^> "wmic.exe"' call terminate
```

Comment: Ok, so i used the 'list' command to first of all find that open image process. I used command:
`wmic process where <name like "image%"> list brief`
but I get the following text:
_The system cannot find the file specified_
I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what :D

Comment: Don't use `<` or `>`.